# Why would my core_config_data table be empty?

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a live functional Magento implementation and have today tried out a new staging environment using Vagrant and Puppet. For reference here is the repo I used.
https://github.com/matthewsplant/magento-vagrant-puppet

My problem is once I’ve imported my SQL dump from the live environment and go to make the base url changes for a localhost I find a completely empty table.

Why might this be? On checking back on my live environment, I find the same (of course) 
There is a core_config_data table but it has no content.

I’d really appreciate a pointer

Comment: An empty core_config_data is not a good sign. Whatever you do next, don't refresh your cache on your live environment. I'd suggest starting to look for a recent database backup.

Comment: Check your SQL file and see if there's any insert statements after the create table statement. As for how it happened, it may have got dropped and not repopulated due to a bad import. As far as I know there is no way to regenerate this table, it holds critical info needed for Magento to run. As an added measure next time it may be best to backup the database before importing a full backup. If foreign keys get in the way it could get messy depending on the version.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was, there seems to be more than one  core_config_data  at least in the Bitnami stack anyway.

I was looking here:

`SELECT * FROM magentodb.core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%base_url’;`

when I should have been looking here: -

`SELECT * FROM magentodb.mage_core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%base_url’;`

This worked for me, I hope this helps others.

Comment: It seems you input a table prefix on installation